# When I tap too quickly, Two or more same DialogFragment pop up. However this is happening in only Android emulator, not in real device. Any advice?

Tags: android, toggle, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Right now, I am calling this function before calling the fragment

```
fun toggleUIEventsListener(delay: Long = 1000) {
    activity?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
    Timer().schedule(delay) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it will happen in a real device as well. Check in other phones and try tapping as fast as you can (twice) and you will realise that its happening in some real devices as well.

The way you can fix this is... make a boolean say, `isClicked`, set it to `true` when its been clicked and then do not allow user to click it for atleast 3 seconds, after that the user should again be able to click that button.

Comment: Thanks so much, though I added the delay of only 1 second, it's working fine now!

Comment: Glad i could help.